# Word count across subset of columns in one new column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(g = c("1", "2", "3"), x = c("This is text.", "This is text too.", 
"This is no text"), y = c("What is text?", "Can it eat text?", 
"Maybe I will try.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I would like to count the number of words across the columns `x` and `y` and sum up the value to get one column with the total number of words used per column. It is important that I am able to subset the data. The result shoud look like this:

```
structure(list(g = c("1", "2", "3"), x = c("This is text.", "This is text too.", 
"This is no text"), y = c("What is text?", "Can it eat text?", 
"Maybe I will try."), z = c("6", "8", "8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I have tried using `str_count(" ")` with different regex expressions in combination with `across` or `apply` but I do not seem to get the solution.

I did not anticipate in my original question that columns with `NA` cells in them would be problematic, but I do. So any solution needs to be able to handle `NA` cells as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
df$z = stringi::stri_count_words(paste(df$x, df$y))

  g                 x                 y z
1 1     This is text.     What is text? 6
2 2 This is text too.  Can it eat text? 8
3 3   This is no text Maybe I will try. 8
```

Or

```
df$z = lengths(gregexpr("\\b\\w+\\b", paste(df$x, df$y)))
```

Comment: Thank you, stringi worked like a charm for my purpose and could handle `NA`s.

Answer (score 4):

Here solution using `tokenizers`:

```r
library(tokenizers)

df <- 
  structure(list(g = c("1", "2", "3"), x = c("This is text.", "This is text too.", 
  "This is no text"), y = c("What is text?", "Can it eat text?", 
  "Maybe I will try.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -3L))

df$z = tokenizers::count_words(df$x) + tokenizers::count_words(df$y)

df
#>   g                 x                 y z
#> 1 1     This is text.     What is text? 6
#> 2 2 This is text too.  Can it eat text? 8
#> 3 3   This is no text Maybe I will try. 8
```

If you prefer pure R:

```
df$z <- rowSums(
  sapply(df[,c("x","y")],function(x)  
    sapply(gregexpr("\\b\\w+\\b", x) , function(x) 
      if(x[[1]] > 0) length(x) else 0)))
```

Note that `\w+` matches all words and `\b` matches word boundaries, though i believe "\w" suffices

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the tokenizer package! It looks really cool. Are any of the two solutions able to handle `NA` columns?

Comment: In the first case you use `df$z = tokenizers::count_words(ifelse(is.na(df$x), "", df$x)) + tokenizers::count_words(ifelse(is.na(df$y), "", dfy))`  In the second case you replace `if(x[[1]] > 0)` with `if(!is.na(x[[1]]) && x[[1]]> 0 )`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_split` and then count the length of the result.
For simplicity, I added a column xy that has the combined words of x and y:

```
my_df <- my_df %>% mutate(xy= paste(x, y))
z <- c(rep(0, length(my_df$xy)))
for (i in 1:length(my_df$xy)) z[i]<-length(str_split_fixed(my_df$xy[i], " ", Inf))
cbind(my_df, z)
```